# render template with the data from a function you just runned on flask

Tags: python, html, flask

When I try to render a flask template with the result of a function it says "y value is not defined"

My function:

```
functiona (x):
    y=x+1
    return y
```

My flask:

```
@app.route('/example')
def example():
    functiona (1)
    return render_template(template.html, y=y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result of function to a variable. Then you'll be able to use it later, e.g. in the next line

```py
@app.route('/example')
def example():
    y = functiona (1)
    return render_template(template.html, y=y)
```